# Toggling multiple buttons in a grid on one click

Tags: javascript

I have created a grid of buttons in javascript. When I click on a button it turns from black to yellow and vice versa. I would like to modify my code so that when I click a button, it also toggles the top, bottom, left and right buttons too.

Here is my code:

```
function toggle(i,j) {
  b=document.getElementById("but_" + i + j)
  t = b.innerHTML
  if (t=="X") {b.innerHTML = "O";
               b.setAttribute( "style", "color:red; background-color:yellow" )
              }
  if (t=="O") {b.innerHTML = "X";
               b.setAttribute( "style", "color:white; background-color:black" )
              }
}

function press(i,j) {
   toggle( i, j )
}


function generateGrid() {
    var d = document.getElementById("button-grid");
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    d.appendChild(table);
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            var row = document.createElement("tr");
            for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                    var cell = document.createElement("td");
                    cell.innerHTML = "<button type=button id=but_" + i + j +
                                     " onclick=\"press(" +i + ',' +j + ")\"" + 
                                     " style=\"color:red; background-color:yellow\"" +
                                     ">O</button>" ;
                    row.appendChild(cell);
            }
            table.appendChild(row);
    }
    toggle(2,2)
}

window.onload = function() {
    generateGrid();
};
```

If you need any more information let me know, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your `press` function to toggle the other buttons :

```
function press() {
    toggle(i, j);
    toggle(i-1, j);
    toggle(i+1, j);
    toggle(i, j-1);
    toggle(i, j+1);
}
```

You would have to adapt your `toggle` function to handle out of bound parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This solves it for the buttons in the middle, however how can I get it so when I toggle a button on the left or right edge it just toggles top and bottom, and when I toggle a button on the top or bottom edge it just toggles the eft and right.

Comment: Thank you for your edit, however this has broken my code and now on click nothing is toggled

Comment: Just check if the button you clicked is on a border (i=0 or i=4 or j=0 or j=4), and  call the `toggle` button accordingly. You just need a couple of `if` statements in the `press` function.

Comment: Would you be able to advise what my if statement should look like?

Comment: Have you tried something? What is causing you difficulties?

Comment: I've tried 'if function press(0,2)' then followed by the toggles however this doesn't seem to be working